# Caret package object ‘map_dfr’ is not exported by 'namespace:purrr'

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm having issues using library("caret") after a new install of the package.

The package has been successfully installed, as well as all dependencies, per the thread:  https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/411

```
install.packages("caret",
             repos = "http://cran.r-project.org", 
             dependencies = c("Depends", "Imports", "Suggests"))
```

The error descrption is: object ‘map_dfr’ is not exported by 'namespace:purrr'

The console recognizes the package because load(ca[tab])  will bring up a select screen for caret.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade `purrr` to at least **v0.2.3**, which is when `purrr::map_dfr()` was introduced.